# variable r might not have been initialized

Tags: java, final

There's a very simple program:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] p) {
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(r);
            }
        };
        r.run();
    }
}
```

And this gives:

```
$ javac A.java 
A.java:6: variable r might not have been initialized
                System.out.println(r);
                                   ^
1 error
```

1. Why?
2. How can a Runnable reference a variable pointing to it?

(In the real code, there is one more level (a listener), and referencing via `this` does not work)

Answer (score 7):

In this case, you can use "this" to avoid the compilation error:

```
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(this); // Avoid compilation error by using this
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

To answer your second question:

```
Runnable outer = new Object() {
   public final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    };
}.r;
outer.run();
```

should work.

Here the compiler sees that r will have been initialized through the implicit constructor.

For your tiny example, it would be enough to move the `final Runnable r` outside the main method and say:

```
new A().r.run();
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case your `new Runnable` is being created before `r`, because of order of operations everything to the right side of an assignment operator is performed before the assignment. This means that `r` is not in scope when your Runnable is declared, and thus it doesn't know what it is inside the `run` method.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `r` variable in the scope of your `run()` method, you are trying to print out some value **during** it's initialization... That's why it `"might not have been initialized"`.

Answer (score 1):

just use "this" in the Runnable in the place of "r" )))  works fine.  Then you do not need to add the "outer" Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

The working code is:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] p) {
        class RunnableHolder { Runnable r; };
        final RunnableHolder r = new RunnableHolder();
        r.r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(r.r);
            }
        };
        r.r.run();
    }
}
```

So it *is* possible to *"unfinal"* a variable using an auxiliary object.

It looks like this construct (an auxiliary object whose fields may be accessed from a Runnable) is exactly what the designers of Java tried to disallow. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A {
    private static Runnable r; 
    public static void main(String[] p) {
        r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(r);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This should work! And there is no **r** in the scope of run and thus it cannot be found in the anonymous implementation.